# What to do when model stops learning after some epochs

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, semantic-segmentation

I am training a segmentation model on 3D data, after around 170 epochs which took around 4 days, I notice the model is no more learning and the dice score is at 0.51. What is the best approach at this point to keep model learning?
Learning rate: 1e-4
Batch size: 6
optimizer: adamw
loss: generalized dice loss
PS: there are more augmentation in training data than validation data, this might be the reason, the validation loss curve is below training loss curve

[image]
[image]

Comment: There are hundreds of things you could try: Muck around with hyper-parameters, use a learning rate scheduler, change the model structure, more augmentation, less augmentation. It's just a matter of experimentation. I'd suggest using a grid search on a smaller sample that doesn't take 4 days to train, then use those values on the real training set.

Comment: Additional to @Recessive's response, very specifically, go for smaller learning rate. As he suggested, you can use learning rate scheduler for that, which will reduce learning rate as epochs pass.

Comment: i already tried reduce on plateau but tht did not helped much